# How to make a loop that goes to a file path and count the files on each directory

Tags: java, excel

I have a program that reads an excel file and creates directories from some content taken from that file, I want to count the number of files on each directory. Is there a way to give a function the path of the file and have that function print directories names along with the count of files inside each directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
String filePath = "YOUR_FILE_PATH";
File folder = new File(filePath);
File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
```

Then you can loop through fileList.
Check if it is directory using isDirectory() function and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8:

Files.list(Paths.get("your/path/here")) for a Stream of files.
Files.list(Paths.get("your/path/here")).count() for a number of files.